# How do I remove Facebook contacts from the Windows 8 People app?

Tags: facebook, windows-8-people-app

I have the People app on my start menu. I have it sync with Facebook. I have since unfriended some people on Facebook, but they are still showing up in the People app.

The People app suggests going to Facebook and deleting the contacts, but they are still there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove your Facebook account entirely from People, reboot, then connect FB to People again and see what happens. (I have "varied luck" with People, as well, but regarding Facebook, that has worked for me in the past.)